# onclick detection on bgiframe in jquery

Tags: jquery, bgiframe

I am trying to find way, to detect onclick event on bgiframe if possible.
The reason behind this is,
since i am using a jquery dialog in ie6, with bgiframe plugin included.
I am not able to bind the

```
$('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function() { $dialog.dialog("close"); });
```

And therefore i am not able to close the dialog, if click anywhere outside the dialog window.
IF i remove the bgiframe plugin everything works fine.
Is there any way this functionality can be achieved along with bgiframe in place. Or may be along my lines of thought if possible.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There's no way set an onclick event to an iframe.  But you could modify bgiframe to load a div the size of the iframe inside the iframe, and set an onclick event to that div, which would close the widget overlay.